# Three.JS - Remove yellow box when using EdgesGeometry, LineSegments, and BoxHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Three.js Version:** 82

I'm looking at this example here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_helpers

Notice that there are yellow boxes around the models. I was using version 79 and was using **THREE.EdgesHelper** to outline my 3D objects I made in Blender, but THREE.EdgesHelper was replaced by **THREE.EdgesGeometry**. I wanted to see an example of this, and the only one I could find is linked above.

I dove into the **line** and **BoxHelper** objects, but I didn't notice anything that would allow me to get rid of those yellow boxes.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4nbjvmpe/

Here is the code from the JSFiddle:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );

    // controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // ambient
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

    // light
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position.set( 20, 20, 0 );
    scene.add( light );

    // geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 12, 8 );

    // material
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x00ffff, 
        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );

    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    // CUSTOM
    // This is where I create the outline mesh.
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    scene.add( group );
    group.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges);
    group.add(line);
    line.material.depthTest = true;
    line.material.opacity = 0.25;
    line.material.transparent = false;
    this.outlineMesh = new THREE.BoxHelper(line);
    scene.add(this.outlineMesh);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link, so that i look into your code and edit as well.

Comment: I edited my question and added the JSFiddle link and code.

Comment: if you don't want that yellow wireframe box around your sphere, then simply don't add `this.outlineMesh = new THREE.BoxHelper(line); scene.add(this.outlineMesh);` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/5pezw5cn/)

Comment: Cool, that works. You can write that as an answer, and I'll accept it. I thought you would need to add the mesh to the scene like you would need to in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply comment `this.outlineMesh = new THREE.BoxHelper(line);` and `scene.add(this.outlineMesh);`. you will get want you want.